# @Inject a @Stateless-bean into @Singleton/@ApplicationScoped-bean

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, thread-safety, ejb

I inject a Java EE `@Stateless`-bean into a `@Singleton`/`@ApplicationScoped`-bean:

```
@Stateless
public class MyStateless {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public void persist(User u){ 

        // for each thread the emProxy is the same
        log.info("emProxy={0}", em.toString());

        // for each thread the emDelegate is differently
        log.info("emDelegate={0}", em.getDelegate().toString());

        // this is definitly thread-safe !
        em.persist(u);

    }
}
```

**version 1:**

```
@javax.ejb.Singleton
public class MySingleton{

    @Inject
    private MyStateless stateless;

    public void persistUser(){
        // is this thread safe?
        stateless.persist(new User("hello"));
    }
}
```

**version 2:**

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MySingleton{

    @Inject
    private MyStateless stateless;

    public void persistUser(){
        // is this thread safe?
        stateless.persist(new User("hello"));
    }
}
```

**version 3:**

```
@javax.ejb.Singleton
@ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.BEAN)
public class MySingleton{

    @Inject
    private MyStateless stateless;

    public void persistUser(){
        // is this hread safe ?
        stateless.persist(new User("hello"));
    }
}
```

**And I have the following statement:**

"If I inject a `@Stateless`-bean into any kind of `@Singleton` or `@ApplicationScoped`-bean, then for each call of `persistUser()` **the container pool will provide another (and not necessarily the same)** instance of `MyStateless`. Thus, there is no 1:1-relation between `@Stateless`-bean and the `@Singleton`/ `@ApplicationScoped`-bean. That also means, the container managed `entiyManager` injected in my `@Stateless`-bean which is indirectly used by my `@Singleton`/`@ApplicationScoped`-bean through the method `persistUser()` is **thread-safe**."

**Is the above statement right for all 3 versions or will they behave differently with my stateless bean?**

**And please look at the following special case (version 4):**

```
@javax.ejb.Singleton
public class MySingleton {

    @Resource private ManagedScheduledExecutorService managedExecutor;

    @Inject
    private MyStateless stateless;

    public void persistUser(){
        // is this thread safe?
        for(int i=0; i<=4;i++){
            managedExecutor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(() 
            -> stateless.persist(new User("hello_" + i)) , 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
    }
}
```

**Is version 4 thread safe?** It must, because I use a method from a `stateless`-bean as `Runnable` and by definition a container managed `entityManager` within a `stateless`-bean must be thread-safe. Am I right?

Looking at the logs, each thread prints the same `entityManager`-proxy:

```
emProxy = org.jboss.as.jpa.container.TransactionScopedEntityManager@3297c304
```

but the delegate for each tread is differently (delegate to the underlying persistence provider hibernate):

```
emDelegate = SessionImpl(2028358710<open>)
```

The **proxy** for `entityManager` is the same on each thread, but the **delegate** of the `entityManager`-proxy on each thread is differently, hence it is thread-safe. Am I right? Or do I also need different `entityManager`-proxies for each thread to be thread-safe?

Btw, there is no difference, if I change `MyStateless` to `@ApplicationScoped`

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyStateless {..}
```

If I use `@ApplicationScoped`, then all simultanously running threads have equal `entityManager`-**proxies** but different `entityManager`-**delegates**. So I cannot see any reason to choose `@Stateless` instead of `@ApplicationScoped`.

**Conclusion:**

There are no problems in these cases above:

"The same proxies can be used in simultanously running threads as long as their delegates are different." What these proxies are (entityManager, stateless beans, etc. does NOT matter.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the JPA specs (version 2.1, chapter 7.2):

> An entity manager must not be shared among multiple concurrently executing threads, as the entity manager and persistence context are not required to be threadsafe. Entity managers must only be accessed in a single-threaded manner.

The `MyStateless` bean can be used by many clients, because the application server takes care of the injected `EntityManager`. So `MyStateless` is thread safe to the outside world; accessing its `EntityManager` from manually spawned threads within the container (i.e. threads created not using the application server's facilities, like the `ManagedExecutorService`), would be unsafe. I am not even certain that using the same `EntityManager`, even from container-managed threads, is safe. Using it concurrently from threads corresponding to multiple clients is, of course, safe. See also in the EJB specs (version 3.2, chapter 4.8.5):

> It is legal to store Java EE objects that do not support concurrent access (e.g. references to Java Persistence entity managers or stateful session beans) within the singleton session bean instance state. However, it is the responsibility of the Bean Provider to ensure such objects are not accessed by more than one thread at a time.

With this in mind, versions 1, 2, 3 of accessing `MyStateless` are OK, as long as they do not occur in manually spawned threads. Version 4 will be OK *as it is* only because (a) the threads are container-managed, so the container will make sure to use a different `EntityManager` in each and (b) the workloads of each thread are independent - can run in different transactions.

And indeed there is no 1-1 relation between the injection "client" and the `MyStateless` injected bean. Actually the container should inject only a proxy to each injection point and the proxy is responsible for resolving the appropriate instance to use.

Comment: Does this mean that the following code which is executed within the @Singleton is NOT thread-safe?: `@Resource private ManagedScheduledExecutorService managedExecutor;...public void task(){managedExecutor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(() -> stateless.persist(new User("hello"))}..
, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`

Comment: The `stateless.persist(new User("hello"))` within the `ManagedExecutorService` must be per definition thread-safe because I use a `stateless`-bean and in each `stateless`-bean there is a thread-safe `entityManager`. So it is overall thread-safe. Am I right?

Comment: I adapted my question above to consider the special case with `@Singleton` and `ManagedExecutorService`.

Comment: I included the logs for the `entityManager` proxy and delegates in my question and found out that:  The proxy for `entityManager` is the same on each thread, but the delegate of the `entityManager`-proxy on each thread is differently, hence it is thread-safe. As long as I have different delegates, it is thread safe. It does not matter if the proxy is the same. Am I right? Or do I also need different `entityManager`-proxy for each thread to be thread-safe?

Comment: I am not certain what happens with container-managed threads (as I wrote above). Apparently, as per your observations, container-managed threads get a correct, separate instance of the `EntityManager`. If the workload of each thread is independent of the others, then this will most probably work. But the fact that the EMs are different also implies separate transactions, so if the threads need to cooperate on the same data, then I believe the EM should be treated as non-thread-safe.

Comment: Thanks! I have only one important question: What does this mean to have the SAME `entityManager`-PROXY for each thread? The delegate of this proxy is different, and this is the sign that each thread uses different entityManagers. Am I right? Or do I also need different  `entityManager`-PROXIES for each thread to secure thread-safety?

Comment: The proxy has only one responsibility: to locate the appropriate, real instance of the bean (the delegate you speak of) and invoke it. So no worries it is *absolutely normal* for the injected "scoped proxy" to be the same instance.

Comment: As I read your answer above "With this in mind, all versions (1, 2, 3) of accessing MyStateless are OK, as long as they do not occur in manually spawned threads." I conclude that "version 4" is NOT allowed because MyStateless occurs in different threads simultanously. Am I right?

Comment: Updated answer - in the specific case demonstrated in the question where the thread are container-managed and the workloads independent, it should not cause problems.

Comment: Yes, I cannot see any problems for now. But one thing I dont understand: I only changed the scope of `MyStateless.class` to `@ApplicationScoped` instead of `@Stateless` for 'version 4' to see if the container uses different `EntityManager`-Delegates for each thread. And indeed, it uses the same `EntityManager`-Proxy for all threads but different `EntityManager`-Delegates. So it has the SAME behaviour as the `@Stateless`-version. So why should I annotate `@Stateless` instead of `@ApplicationScoped` for `MyStateless.class`? Are there any caveats?

Comment: There are lots of resources on the difference of `Stateless` and `@ApplicationScoped`, I'd suggest some searching & reading independent of this question (because we are slowly going off-topic). One difference that comes to mind as an example is how session EJBs and CDI beans handle transactions (default: ON for EJBs, OFF for CDI). There are more subtle differences, which may or may not affect your specific case.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help. The one which helped me very much was your statement about proxy and delegates: The same proxies can be used in simultanously running threads as long as their delegates are different.